# Which license do I need to cover TFS2017 server and client machine?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

We are going to work together with another company which using TFS/Octopus Deploy.

The item is currently in phase one, which includes building the platform and ensuring that all components work together cohesively.

I'm confused with the license required with TFS. It's easy to understand the license for TFS server. However, there seems to be a client license for each client, why we need two license for a product? And what's the association  with TFS client license  / VS or MSDN subscription?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TFS is licensed on a Server/CAL model. Thus, you need 1 Server license for the TFS server and 1 TFS CAL (client access license) for each user that will use TFS features.

That TFS CAL covers the usage no matter how the user accesses TFS (i.e. Visual Studio, Eclipse, Web Access client, Excel, MSProject, 3rd party tool, ect, etc).

The two ways to acquire TFS CALs are:

1. Purchase a TFS User CAL
2. 1 TFS CAL (and 1 TFS Server license) is included in **each Visual
   Studio/MSDN subscription**. Thus, anyone who has an active MSDN
   subscription assigned to them is covered with a TFS CAL.

> Client access licenses (CALs) aren’t required for people who just
>   access work items – assign them “**Stakeholder**” access, which is
>   free.
>
> Extensions to TFS such as **Test Manager**, **Package Management**,
>   and **Private Pipelines** require an **additional purchase**. Some TFS
>   Extensions are included with Visual Studio Enterprise subscriptions
>   and many others are free. Paid extensions can also be purchased
>   monthly, no Visual Studio subscription is required.

More details please refer below two blogs:

- [Understand TFS Licensing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/govdev/2012/05/14/understand-tfs-licensing/)
- [Team Foundation Server 2017 Licensing](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-pricing/)

Answer (score 1):

As you have already stated you need a license for TFS itself, but if you have a single Visual Studio subscription this is included.

Clients connecting to TFS might need a license depending on the [access level](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/change-access-levels) needed. A lot of the planning features are free (stakeholder level) whereas source code and more advanced features will require either a Basic (most features except Test) or Enterprise (all features) level access.

Basic level can be obtained by either buying it directly through VSTS or by buying a product that includes a CAL license e.g. Visual Studio subscription.

For smaller teams, you can use TFS/VSTS for free but with a maximum of 5 users.

You can read more on the [Team Foundation Server pricing page](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-pricing/).